# SUM(MAX(Fields.Amount)) not working in telerik reporting

Tags: telerik-reporting

SUM(MAX(Fields.Amount)) not working in Telerik reporting is there any relevant expression available

Comment: Nested aggregate functions don't make much sense and I am not surprised this doesn't work. Can you give more information about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Your current syntax is trying to find the sum of the maximum Amount which is identical to just doing `MAX(Fields.Amount)` because there is only ever a single MAX.